# How to remove repeated object values from arrayList Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arraylist

I have an arrayList with objects in it. I need to show only one value, if objects has the same values.

For Example : [ {a:0,b:1},{a:1,b:0},{a:0,b:1} ] 
From the above example I need to show only the first and second object and skip the third object because it is as same as first object.

Note : the objects in array can be infinite, I cant hardcode the index value. Can anyone help me out the generic solution.

This is what I have tried:

```
points = [];
newarr = [];
locArray = [ {a:0,b:1},{a:1,b:0},{a:0,b:1} ];

if(abc!=null){
removeDuplicateCoordinates();
                        $.each(newarr,function(key,val){
                           points.push([val.a,val.b]);

                        });

}

function removeDuplicateCoordinates(){
                var arr = locArray;
                $.each(arr, function(index,item){
                    if(searchForItem(newarr,item)<0){
                        newarr.push(item);
                    }
                });
            }
            function searchForItem(array, item){
                var i, j, current;
                for(i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
                    if(item.length === array[i].length){
                        current = array[i];
                        for(j = 0; j < item.length && item[j] === current[j]; ++j);
                        if(j === item.length)
                            return i;
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }
```

Comment: Take a look at these solutions: http://jsperf.com/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-strings-javascript, http://jsperf.com/dedup-int-array. Hope you'll adopt them easily. If not, choose one You like, and we'll try to implement it.

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants : can you please implement the structure I have.Its becoming difficult for me to understand the links you provided for reference.

Comment: Should you preserve source array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) will not compare objects.

[We know that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects):

> In JavaScript objects are a reference type. Two distinct objects are never equal, even if they have the same properties. Only comparing the same object reference with itself yields true.

So, easiest and **fastest** way **IMHO**, will be to compare by yourself.
Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/6aLdt6ty/)

```
var locArray = [{ a: 0, b: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 0 }, { a: 0, b: 1 }];

//We will try to find if point alrady exists in array
Array.prototype.indexOfPoint = function(point) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var arrPoint = this[i];
        if (arrPoint.a === point.a && arrPoint.b === point.b)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
};

Array.prototype.uniquePoints = function() {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var currentPoint = this[i];
        if (a.indexOfPoint(currentPoint) < 0) {
            a.push(currentPoint);
        }
    }
    return a;
};

var newarr = locArray.uniquePoints();
console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/765j0ht4/1/)
try this one

```
    newarr = [];
    testarr = [];
    locArray = [ {a:0,b:1},{a:1,b:0},{a:0,b:1} ];
    for (var i = 0; i<locArray.length;i++)
        {
    var idx = $.inArray(String(locArray[i].a)+String(locArray[i].b), testarr);
    if (idx == -1) {
      testarr.push(String(locArray[i].a)+String(locArray[i].b));
      newarr.push(locArray[i]);
        }
     }
    console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite methods:

```
usedArray = {};
locArray = [ {a:0,b:1},{a:1,b:0},{a:0,b:1} ];
for (key in locArray) {
    if (usedArray[JSON.stringify(locArray[key])] == undefined) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(locArray[key]));
        usedArray[JSON.stringify(locArray[key])] = true;
    }
}
```

Don't know anything about how fast it is, but it works for me everytime. Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo81j2cw/).

instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(locArray[key]));` You can populate new array:

```
newarr.push(locArray[key]);
```

**EDIT**

Test width 100000 objects in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo81j2cw/5/)
~300ms i can live with that.

Comment: Json stringify is pretty heaviweight operation to use it in loop, don't you think so?

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants yes it is heavyweight however everything depends on how many elements locArray contains. Plus adding some optimization and vuolia it performs not so badly.

Comment: agree It always depends, and premature optimization is evil :)